# Drupal7 custom menu code in template adds stray div for no reason

Tags: templates, drupal, menu

I am hoping someone more knowledgeable here can point out what the problem is.

I am making a custom menu for Drupal7 for a particular theme I am working on, which is using the menu_views module.  Everything works pretty nicely until I pass the view menu entry over to menu_views to parse, in which case drupal adds a broken `<div class=">...</div>` around the parent UL element of the view menu.. I have gone through the code and don't see how this is even happening.. If I comment out the call to the view parsing, then it doesn't add this DIV, but that view parsing shouldnt' be touching the parent UL element?

Here is how the HTML is output:

```
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="parent_">
    <div class="> <li class=" first=" " expanded=" " active-trail "=" "><a href="/pt-br/produtos/lista " title=" " class="active-trail active ">Por nome</a>
        <ul class="menu-content collapsed in " id=" ">
            <div class="view view-nameofview view-id-nameofview etc ">
                <div class="view-content ">
                    <div class="item-list ">
                        <ul class="views-summary ">
                            <li><a href="/pt-br/produtos/lista/%C3%A1 ">Á</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Here is the template code that causes this:

```
function  bstheme_menu_link__main_menu($variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];

    // resolve conflict with menu_views module
    if (module_exists('menu_views') && $element['#href'] == '<view>') {

        return _bstheme_menu_views_menu_link($variables);   //<<<< IF I COMMENT OUT THIS THE OUTPUT IS FINE
    }

    static $item_id = 0;
    // Add an ID for easy identifying in jquery and such 
    $element['#attributes']['id'] = 'menu_'.str_replace(' ', '_',strtolower($element['#title']));

    if(!empty($element['#original_link']['menu_name']) && $element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'main-menu'){ 
        if($element['#original_link']['has_children'] == 1){
            $element['#attributes']['data-target'] = "jquery_updates_this";
            $element['#attributes']['data-toggle'] = "collapse";
        }

        // add class parent and remove leaf
        $classes_count = count($element['#attributes']['class']);
        for($i=0;$i<$classes_count;++$i){
            if($element['#attributes']['class'][$i] == 'expanded'){
                //$element['#attributes']['class'][$i] = 'collapse';
            }   
            if($element['#original_link']['plid'] == 0){
                if($element['#attributes']['class'][$i] == 'leaf'){
                    unset($element['#attributes']['class'][$i]);
                } 
            }
            else{   
                if($element['#attributes']['class'][$i] == 'leaf'){
                    $element['#attributes']['class'][$i] = '';
                }

            }
        }  
    }

    // code to add a span item for the glythicons
    $switch = $element['#original_link']['has_children'];

    $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
    if($switch == 1) {
        $linktext =  $element['#title'] . '<span class="arrow"></span>';
    } else {
        $linktext = $element['#title'];
    }

    // if there's a submenu, send the parsing to the custom function instead of the main one to wrap different classes
    if ($element['#below']) {
        foreach ($element['#below'] as $key => $val) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {             
                $element['#below'][$key]['#theme'] = 'menu_link__main_menu_inner'; // 2 lavel 
            }
        }
        $element['#below']['#theme_wrappers'][0] = 'menu_tree__main_menu_inner';  // 2 lavel 
        $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
        $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-toggle';
    }    

    //$sub_menu = $element['#below'] ? drupal_render($element['#below']) : '';
    $output = l($linktext, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . '</li>'."\n";
}

function _bstheme_menu_views_menu_link(&$variables) {
    // Only intercept if this menu link is a view.
    $view = _menu_views_replace_menu_item($variables['element']);// <<< MENU VIEWS PARSING

    if ($view !== FALSE) {
        if (!empty($view)) {
            $sub_menu = '';
            if ($variables['element']['#below']) {
                $sub_menu = render($variables['element']['#below']);
            }
            return '' . $view . $sub_menu . "\n";  // <<< RETURN PATH
        }
        return '';
    }
    return theme('menu_views_menu_link_default', $variables);
}
```

Any pointers on how to troubleshoot something like this, or if someone has encountered this problem before and has a solution, would be greatly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it's apparent you're using Drupal 7.

First things first, you may want to enable theme debug mode. This allows for you to see where the theming function that caused your

You can do so by putting the following line in your settings.php  file

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

Flush your caches after you make this change.

You will now have debug code output to your Drupal HTML source, when you view the site's source. An example of the type of output is shown below:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('page') -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
  x page--front.tpl.php
  * page--node.tpl.php
  * page.tpl.php
-->
```

With this debug, you should be able to see exactly which theme functions run, in which order, and by working through them from start to finish, you should be able to determine between which theme is responsible.

At this point, if you want to keep Drupal-best-practices, copy the file name suggestion from the debug output to a folder inside your theme folder. I usually put all template overrides in a sub-directory inside it.

In the case above, if it was page.tpl.php, I'd copy it to /themes/mytheme/templates/, and go hack on it to see whether the offending div is being generated there.

Best of luck, and if you hit a stuck end, I'd be happy to help point you in a direction more specific to your specific user case.

Best,

Karl

Comment: It's not related to templating, it's functions hooking into and overriding the drupal menu code conflicting with similar code from another module, breaking the way drupal7 outputs the main_menu in some fantastical and weird way